# I can not begin to login into Software

Tags: java, authentication, oracle11g, passwords

I have the following problem, I have made ​​software in Java and JPA, which connects to an Oracle database. To access the software, I always put a username and password, but one day, when I set the username and password could not access the software, because an error appeared. when I look at the console, I noticed the following error.

```
    09:34:25,184 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28001: the password has expired ); - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28001: the password has expired )) 

09:34:25,235 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f57e6f6:9af:5360ed6f:3e status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f57e6f6:9af:5360ed6f:3e status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >)

09:34:25,245 ERROR [lifecycle] JSF1054: (Phase ID: INVOKE_APPLICATION 5, View ID: /login.xhtml) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@8e2cf] 09:34:25,285 ERROR [Exceptions] handled and logged exception
```

Software called SGPD, these are some of your files:

---

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Persistence deployment descriptor for dev profile -->
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
   version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="sgpd" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         <jta-data-source>java:/sgpdDatasource</jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"     value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />-->                 
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"     value="java:/sgpdEntityManagerFactory" />                        
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

---

Login-config.xml

```
<application-policy name="EncryptDBPassword">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.resource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="username">sgpd</module-option>
            <module-option name="password">312b63d33ab936b3</module-option>
         <module-option name = "managedConnectionFactoryName">jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=sgpdDatasource</module-option>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</application-policy>
```

---

sgpd-ds.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datasources PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS JCA Config 1.5//EN"
                         "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-ds_1_5.dtd">
<datasources>
 <local-tx-datasource>
  <jndi-name>sgpdDatasource</jndi-name>
  <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</connection-url>
  <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>

 <security-domain>EncryptDBPassword</security-domain>   
 </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Comment: Please translate your title

Comment: From your logs: *the password has expired*

Comment: You need to consult Oracle database admin to reset password.

Answer (score 0):

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28001: the password has expired

Please consult your DBA who administers the database and have him reset the password for the user you use to connect to the database.